# Pushforward Lorentz metric: $ds^2=dxdy $

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, semi-riemannian-geometry, pushforward

Consider an open embedding $\varphi:\Bbb R^{1,1}_- \hookrightarrow (0,1)^2$ with $\varphi(x_1,x_2)=(e^{x_1},e^{x_2})$

I need to put a metric on $(0,1)^2$.

Here’s what I know so far. I need to transport the Lorentz metric: $ds^2=dxdy. $

Since my map is a diffeomorphism I can try to push forward the Lorentz metric to $(0,1)^2$.

I know that $n=\log(x)\log(y)$ is a preserved metric of a transformation on $(0,1)^2$ that is related to the classical Lorentz transformation.

I’ve tried to get a metric from this preserved quantity but have not been successful.

> How can I push the Lorentz metric forward?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I have a few comments. The Lorentz metric is usually taken to be (up to a sign), $dt^2-dx^2$. While what you wrote is indeed isometric to the Lorentz metric, but I disagree on using the letters $x$ and $t$, which are usually reserved for space and time respectively. The coordinates you are using are in some sense "null-like", so I would suggest using a different notation.

Comment: To answer your question, note that one can pull-back a metric using a smooth map. But since your map is a diffeomorphism, you can indeed also push forward a metric, which amounts to pulling it back using the inverse map of the given diffeomorphism.

Comment: Another comment is $\operatorname{log}(x) \operatorname{log}(t)$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, not a metric. A metric is a specific kind of tensor, which infinitesimally takes as input $2$ tangent vectors and outputs a number, which is some kind of dot product of the two vectors.

Comment: Could you make an answer please @Malkoun?

Comment: @Malkoun what do you mean by "the coordinates I'm using are null-like in some sense"?

Comment: I will write an answer to explain what I mean, as it is too long to explain in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to explain my comments to the OP's post here. As this is too long to be in the comments, I have decided to include them in an "answer format".

The metric on $2$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime is

$$ g = dt^2 - dx^2.$$

Of course, some people prefer to write it as $-g$. In the end, this is just a matter of convention. Now, let

$u = f_1(t,x) := t+x \quad \text{ and } \quad v = f_2(t,x) := t-x.$

Denote by $f$ the resulting map which maps $(t,x)$ to $(u,v)$, and thus has as components $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Therefore, if we let $h = dudv$, then

$$f^*(h) = dt^2 - dx^2 = g.$$

In other words, $f$ is an isometry from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(t,x)$ and Minkowski metric $g$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(u,v)$ and metric $h = dudv$.

Finally, note that both $du$ and $dv$ are null, meaning that

$h^{-1}(du,du) = 0 \quad \text{ and } h^{-1}(dv,dv) = 0.$

This is what I meant by the statement that $u$ and $v$ are null coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

The new metric in $(0,1)^2$ is $ds^2=\frac{1}{u}du\frac{1}{v}dv.$

This is done by pulling back the Lorentz metric $ds^2=dxdy.$

$\begin{align}
 (\varphi^{-1})^* (dxdy) &=( d((\varphi^{-1})^*x))( d((\varphi^{-1})^*y)) \\
&= (d (x\circ \varphi^{-1}))(d (y\circ \varphi^{-1})) \\
&= (d \log u)(d\log v) \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{u} du\right)\left( \frac{1}{v} dv\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{u} du\frac{1}{v} dv.
\end{align}$